# Загрузка файла на сервер через форму в qwebview

Tags: python, pyqt5, webview, qwebengine

Есть форма, есть webView, собственно интересует, что нужно сделать для того чтобы при клике на кнопку загрузки файла открывалось окно с выбором файла, потому что сейчас при клике ничего не происходит.
Код браузера:

```
from window import Ui_MainWindow

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
import sys
import re

class Browser(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Browser, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.url = self.make_true_url('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
        self.ui.webView.load(self.url)

        self.ui.reloadButton.clicked.connect(self.ui.webView.reload)
        self.ui.backButton.clicked.connect(self.ui.webView.back)
        self.ui.goButton.clicked.connect(self.go_to_page)
        self.ui.urlLine.setText(re.findall("('.+')", str(self.ui.webView.url()))[0][1:-1])

        self.ui.webView.urlChanged.connect(self.update_urlbar)
        self.ui.webView.titleChanged.connect(self.update_title)

    @staticmethod
    def make_true_url(url):
        return QUrl(url) if QUrl(url).scheme() else QUrl('http://' + url)

    def go_to_page(self):
        self.url = self.make_true_url(self.ui.urlLine.text())
        self.ui.webView.load(self.url)

    def update_urlbar(self):
        self.ui.urlLine.setText(re.findall("('.+')", str(self.ui.webView.url()))[0][1:-1])

    def update_title(self):
        title = self.ui.webView.page().title()
        self.setWindowTitle(f'{title} - MiniBrowser')


def start():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    application = Browser()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

window.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtWebEngineWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MiniBrowser")
        MainWindow.resize(842, 630)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(842, 630))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(842, 630))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.webView = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView(self.centralwidget)
        self.webView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 821, 561))
        self.webView.setUrl(QtCore.QUrl("about:blank"))
        self.webView.setObjectName("webView")
        self.backButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.backButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(122, 4, 89, 31))
        self.backButton.setObjectName("backButton")
        self.reloadButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.reloadButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 4, 89, 31))
        self.reloadButton.setObjectName("reloadButton")
        self.urlLine = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.urlLine.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 4, 451, 31))
        self.urlLine.setObjectName("urlLine")
        self.goButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.goButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(660, 4, 71, 31))
        self.goButton.setObjectName("goButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 842, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MiniBrowser", "MiniBrowser"))
        self.backButton.setText(_translate("MiniBrowser", "Back"))
        self.reloadButton.setText(_translate("MiniBrowser", "Reload"))
        self.goButton.setText(_translate("MiniBrowser", "Go"))
```

Flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template

app = Flask('upload')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def main_page():
    return render_template('main.html')
```

HTML форма:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <form method="post", enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <input type="file" name="img" accept="image/*">
   <button type="submit">send</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick добавил код

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста модуль`window.py`

Comment: @S.Nick готово!

Comment: @S.Nick могу добавить еще код сервера, но там просто роутинг на главную страницу где загружается эта форма

Comment: Я думая вам надо добавить все, что поможет как можно быстрее воспроизвести проблему и дать вам какой-либо совет.

Comment: @S.Nick теперь я добавил все

Comment: Посмотрите здесь 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55129643/pyqt5-and-django-how-to-upload-image-using-http-request-multipart-form/55132547#55132547
 вдруг чем-то поможет.